# Python extract numbers from start of string before colon

Tags: python, regex, string

I would like to extract all numbers from the start up to a colon in a string

```
string = '125: 16272'
```

desired result:

```
extracted = '125'
```

the numbers will not be negative or contain decimal places, they are just positive integers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string = '125: 16272'
extracted = string.split(':')[0]
```

use split()

if you need int variable of `extracted` then

```
extracted = int(string.split(':')[0])
```

Please read following link (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_split.htm)